# I have an issue with the PyQt5.QtWidgets

Tags: python, dll, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.8

I work with python3 version and I can't figure out the error with this module "QtWidgets"
here is the code

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

here is the output

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still not having a logical answer but what I did, is upgrading python version from 3.8 to 3.9, and it worked successfully

Edit : the problem was in the dll libraries of QT, the python interpreter cannot find them, what I did , I coppied those .dll libraries from "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms" to the folder where my executable existed and all worked fine.